# How to change terminal style back to default?

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm having problem to change the terminal style in my mac. I would like to change it back to default setting but I don't know how to. I want to remove the heart (as you see from the screenshot). Thank you! (This style was from Flatiron School online free swift coding lesson)

[Terminal Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYnP7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article 
http://osxdaily.com/2013/04/08/add-emoji-command-line-bash-prompt/

would seem to indicate that there is a line in your `.bash_profile` that specifies this emoji using a line that begins with `PS1=`

so try

1. `nano .bash_profile`
2. add a `#` before any line that begins with `PS1=`
3. `ctrl+O` to save
4. return to confirm file name
5. `ctrl+x` to close nano

Answer (score 0):

When in Terminal open the Settings via CMD+, or in the menu bar via "Terminal" > "Settings"

In the top bar close Profiles, now the window should look like this:
[image: The settings panel]

Now choose the Basic profile an hit standard.

Maybe this solves your problem.